# Implement an iterator on a List<List<Integer>> in O(1) space

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

Say you want to implement an `Iterator` on a `List<List<Integer>>` in a constant space environment, how would you proceed?

Another requirement is that using a stack or a queue is not allowed.

You must define the `hasNext()` and `next()` functions.

Comment: iterating through a List does not need any space, it always happens in `O(1)`

Comment: @Michael I think the question is referring to __space__ not time

Comment: @molamk Yeah, got it. Thanks

Comment: "Say you want to implement an Iterator" But I don't want to implement that. *You* want to implement it. Well, more specifically, I suspect that your teacher/professor wants you to implement it. ;)

Comment: Constant space is required. My solution was O(N) where N is the max size of any given list.

Comment: You can keep two standard `Iterator`s in constant space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To iterate over a `List` you need only **a single variable pointing to the current element**.

The method `hasNext` is a simple test between the size of the `List` and the pointer.

The next `method` is a simple extraction using the element at position pointer.

**The pointer is an `int`** so the space is **O(1)**. You can eventually save also a variable for the size of the `List`, but also in this case the space is O(1).

---

The same can be accomplished in a `List` of `List` simply saving two pointers (and eventually two sizes), and can be expanded to any **fixed** of number of nested lists. It can not be used for a variable number of nested lists, because they can be potentially n so in this case the solution needs O(n) of space.

Comment: I like your solution.

Comment: (The original question asked about a list of lists, assignment dump or not.)

Comment: @greybeard probably was a mistake... I saw a simple List at the beginning. Anyway I updated the answer.